# Use 2d array as list of indices for n-D array

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

If I have the following data:

```
A = np.random.random((3, 4, 5))

# np.all(indices < A.shape) is true
indices = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 4],
    ...
    [2, 3, 4]
])
```

How can I use each row of `indices` as a set of axis indices into A to give the following?

```
B = np.array([
    A[0, 0, 0],
    A[1, 2, 4],
    ...
    A[2, 3, 4]
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a 2d example:

```
In [1]: A=np.arange(10,22).reshape(3,4)
In [2]: A
Out[2]: 
array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21]])
In [3]: ind=np.array([[0,1],[1,3],[2,0],[0,2]])
In [4]: ind
Out[4]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 2]])
In [5]: A[ind[:,0],ind[:,1]]
Out[5]: array([11, 17, 18, 12])
```

or for your variables,

```
A[indices[:,0], indices[:,1], indices[:,2]]
```

Or more generally:

```
In [8]: tuple(ind.T)
Out[8]: (array([0, 1, 2, 0]), array([1, 3, 0, 2]))
In [9]: A[tuple(ind.T)]
Out[9]: array([11, 17, 18, 12])
```

This is based on the idea that `A[a,b]` is the same as `A[(a,b)]`.  And when `a` and `b` are matching lists or arrays, it selects values by pairing them up, roughly the same as

```
[A[i,j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

For a `product` like indexing, the index arrays need to have more dimensions.  `ix_` is a handy way of generating such arrays:

```
In [53]: np.ix_(ind[:,0],ind[:,1])
Out[53]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [0]]), array([[1, 3, 0, 2]]))
In [54]: A[np.ix_(ind[:,0],ind[:,1])]
Out[54]: 
array([[11, 13, 10, 12],
       [15, 17, 14, 16],
       [19, 21, 18, 20],
       [11, 13, 10, 12]])

In [56]: A[ind[:,[0]],ind[:,1]]
Out[56]: 
array([[11, 13, 10, 12],
       [15, 17, 14, 16],
       [19, 21, 18, 20],
       [11, 13, 10, 12]])
```

Comment: I was under the impression that passing in multiple lists to an index expression did something more like `itertools.product` rather than zip

Comment: The product like indexing is performed with higher dimensional indexes. I'll add an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) to generate the linear indices and then extract the selective elements from `A` with [`linear-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) using [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) like so -

```
np.take(A,np.ravel_multi_index(indices.T,A.shape))
```